# Joined query producing more results compared to solo query

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I am performing the following query which has an inner join against another table.

```
select count(myTable.name) 
from sch2.sample_detail as myTable 
inner join sch1.otherTable as otherTable on myTable.name = otherTable.name 
where otherTable.is_valid = 1 
  and myTable.name IS NOT NULL;
```

This produces a count of 4912304.

The following is a query just on a single table (my table).

```
SELECT COUNT(myTable.name) 
from sch2.sample_detail as myTable 
where myTable.name IS NOT NULL;
```

This produces a count of 2864654.

But how is this possible? Both queries have the clause `where myTable.name IS NOT NULL`.

Shouldn't the second query produce same results or if not even more cos the second query doesn't have the `otherTable.is_valid = 1` clause?
Why does the inner join produces a higher count of result?

Please advice if there is something I should amend in the 1st query, thanks.

Comment: A join can return _up to_ n * m rows. (Where n is number of rows in 1st table, and m in 2nd table.)

Comment: @jarlh Is there a way I could limit it. Cos I am only concerned with names in myTable. Thus not interested in values from m if m.name doesn't exists in myTable. Was under the impression the inner join took care of this to only capture names that exists in both tables. Guess wrong understanding.

Comment: I'm lost.  The queries are quite difference.  `JOIN`s cqn filter or multiply rows.  And there are different `WHERE` clauses.  Why would you expect them to return the same results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not necessarily same, but I was expecting the join query to at least return less data than the 2nd (Single table) query. But instead the join query is returning more results.

Comment: @Fllappy . . . There are keys with multiple matches.  Nothing surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner, left or cross join can duplicate rows. `sch1.otherTable.name` is not unique and this causing rows duplication because for each row in left table all corresponding rows from right table are being selected, this is normal join behavior.

To get duplicate names list use this query and decide how to remove duplicated rows: filter or distinct or filter by row_number, etc.

```
select count(*) cnt,
       name
  from sch1.otherTable
having count(*)>1
order by cnt desc;
```

If you need  EXISTS (and do not need to select columns from otherTable), use `left semi join`.
Also subquery with distinct can be used to pre-aggregate name before join and filter:

```
select count(myTable.name) 
from sch2.sample_detail as myTable 
LEFT SEMI JOIN (select distinct name from sch1.otherTable otherTable where otherTable.is_valid = 1 ) as otherTable on myTable.name = otherTable.name 
where myTable.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Writing this in HIVE. Left semi join is throwing syntax errors.

Comment: @Fllappy this is because you referencing column where otherTable.is_valid = 1 . For left semi  join you should not reference any column from right table except in ON join condition. Fixed the answer: use subquery

Comment: @Fllappy Also ... where myTable.name IS NOT NULL - is a redundant condition because join on NULL is not happening and is filtered by LEFT SEMI JOIN. you can remove that condition.